# How to write/create a private route in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I tried creating a private route using react-router-dom v6 as shown below in React JS

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import * as ROUTES from './constants/routes';

import { Home, Signin, Signup, Browse } from './pages';
import { IsUserRedirect, ProtectedUserRedirect } from './helpers/routes';

function App() {
  const user=null;
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.HOME} element={<IsUserRedirect user={user} path={ROUTES.BROWSE} />}>
          <Route element={<Home />} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.BROWSE} element={<ProtectedUserRedirect user={user} path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} />}>
          <Route element={<Browse />} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} element={<IsUserRedirect user={user} path={ROUTES.BROWSE} />}>
          <Route element={<Signin />} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} element={<IsUserRedirect user={user} path={ROUTES.BROWSE} />}>
          <Route element={<Signup />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the helper components are implemented as shown below

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const IsUserRedirect = ({path, user, children}) => {
    console.log(Boolean(user))
    return (
        user?<Navigate to={path} replace />:<Outlet />
    )
}

export const ProtectedUserRedirect = ({path, user, children}) => {
    console.log(Boolean(user))
    return (
        user?<Outlet />:<Navigate to={path} replace />
    )
}
```

**NO ERROR AT TERMINAL AND CONSOLE** but I'm not getting any output. The components seems to not rendering properly. Could you please me how to write better private route in v6 of router-dom. Reference: https://dev.to/iamandrewluca/private-route-in-react-router-v6-lg5

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: You set `const user=null;` each render cycle.

Comment: Even on providing a valid object to user same error prevails @DrewReese

Comment: I thought your post said there was no error. What error are your referring to? Would it be possible to create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue? Can you provide a precise set of steps to reproduce any issues?